# Существует ли быстрый алгоритм проверки пересечения линии полигона с собой?

Tags: алгоритм

Есть полигон, заданный некоторым массивом точек, образующих прямые (около 4000). Надо проверить,пересекаются ли эти линии с самими собой.
Метод перебора массива в массиве занимает очень много времени. Есть ли более быстрый способ?

Comment: Речь, наверное, идет об *отрезках* (ребрах полигона), а не о *прямых*.

Comment: @AnT, смысл вопроса не меняется

Comment: Смысл вопроса меняется катастрофически. Для *прямых* задача фактически не имеет смысла, ибо ответ всегда "да".

Answer (score 3):

Классическое решение задачи нахождения всех пересечений в *произвольной свалке* отрезков - алгоритм сканирующей прямой. Однако такой алгоритм интуитивно является чересчур общим, так как не принимает во внимание тот факт, что мы имеем дело не с произвольной свалкой отрезков, а именно с ребрами многоугольника.

Для случая ребер многоугольника более оптимальным (по крайней мере теоретически) представляется следующий подход

1. Сначала выполняем декомопозицию границы многоугольника на монотонные ломаные. Монотонность должна выполняться вдоль какого-то заранее выбранного направления.

   Например, выпуклый многоугольник распадется ровно на две ломаные.
2. Затем запускаем классический алгоритм сканирующей прямой, но в качестве входа для него используем не отдельные отрезки, а целые ломаные, полученные на шаге 1. Направление сканирования должно совпадать с направлением монотонности ломаных.
3. В процессе сканирования проверяем и обрабатываем пересечения между соседними монотонными ломаными (точно так же, как в классическом алгоритме проверяются и обрабатываются пересечения между соседними отрезками).

   Нахождение пересечения двух монотонных ломаных - достаточно простая и эффективно решаемая задача.

Answer (score 1):

Лобовая проверка пересечений всех отрезков друг с другом приводит к квадратичном алгоритму O(n^2)

Можно построить какой-либо вид BSP, например, ограничивающие прямоугольники всех сегментов занести в R-tree и проверять пересечения только для тех сегментов, прямоугольники которых пересекаются. Построение дерева O(nlogn), проверка всех пересечений от O(n)  до O(n^2) (однако последнее относится к плохому случаю типа звезды, когда наличие хотя бы одного пересечения будет выявлено рано). Если предполагаются ещё какие-то действия с отрезками, то построенное BSP может пригодиться.

А можно использовать **метод сканирующей прямой** (sweep-line).

В частности - построенный на его основе алгоритм  Шеймоса-Хои, предназначенного именно для обнаружения пересечений.

[Тут есть описание и даже реализация](http://geomalgorithms.com/a09-_intersect-3.html)

Если понадобится выявить **все** точки пересечения - см. алгоритм Бентли-Оттмана.